# Split Window/Screen same file, second split continuation of first?

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ for Grails coding, and it has a split window feature (vertical and horizontal). I am looking for an IDE or plugin for IDE that can split window/screen, and if it's the same file, have the option of having the second window/screen be an automatic continuation of the first screen.

The idea being, when you scroll the first screen, the second will automatically follow. Basically, I want to be able to read more code on a widescreen monitor.

Can anyone point me in the direction of an IntelliJ setting I might be missing or plugin, or point me to an IDE that can support such a feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone has written a set of patches for NetBeans to do what you want.  Note the date, however.  http://weblogs.java.net/blog/timboudreau/archive/2005/09/followmode_for.html

Otherwise, the closest you will get with an IDE is emacs with follow-mode or vim with :vsplit and using :scrollbind in both windows.

This is an incredibly useful feature, but it's painful to do without IDEA's features when using emacs.  I usually end up splitting vertically and scrolling by hand in IDEA.  It's one plug-in I would definitely consider paying for.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a definitive answer, but to my knowledge that isn't possible in Intellij.  I did a quick search thru the available plugins and I don't see anything there either.  Good luck